# R: Plot 2 graphs below each other and add moving average to each

Tags: r, plot

I'm struggling with the whole plotting in R. I want to have 2 Charts below each other and format them individually. Furthermore I want to add a moving average to each of them. How can I do that? I've managed to have them drawn below each other but I'm still struggling with the moving average.
As an example for a reproducible code I've used SPY and Apple data.

```
getSymbols("SPY")
getSymbols("AAPL")
par(mfrow=2:1)
plot(SPY, main="SPY")

plot(AAPL,main="AAPL")
```

And how can I format them individually? And don't show the gridlines over both charts?

Comment: Hi, you should add library(quantmod) to your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `rollmean` from the `zoo` library:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("SPY")
getSymbols("AAPL")

par(mfrow=2:1)
plot(SPY[, "SPY.Open"], main="SPY", auto.grid=F)
lines(rollmean(SPY, k=30, fill=NA)[, "SPY.Open"], col="red")
plot(AAPL[, "AAPL.Open"], main="AAPL", auto.grid=F)
lines(rollmean(AAPL, k=30, fill=NA)[, "AAPL.Open"], col="red")
```

This plots the opening values along with 30-day moving average. You can change `k` to adjust the window, and `rollmean` also has options for how you want to align the window. By default it is centered.

To remove the gridlines, adding `auto.grid=F` seems to do the trick, from `?plot.xts`.

[image]

You could also brute force it by converting the series to plain numeric vectors:

```
spy.open <- as.vector(SPY[, "SPY.Open"])
plot(spy.open, type="l")
```

[image]